# Centre of a black hole

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, conservation-laws, singularities

In a text intended for people without background in general relativity or quantum mechanics, I read two statements which are false or do not make sense, if I'm correct. Am I correct, and why (not)?

Statement a: "In the middle of a black hole time progresses normally." My objections:
(i) Any conceivable clock with material parts is destroyed when it approaches the centre of the black hole (or even before crossing the event horizon of a stellar black hole). Even a clock consisting of caesium atoms or a collection of decaying free neutrons would succumb. (Never mind our astronaut carrying the clock wouldn't be able to report observations to Earth and that he or she would perish before the clock fails.)
(ii) When a clock enters the central region where the Planck mass density is reached, quantum effects become dominant and time in the every day sense loses its meaning ("quantum foam", "probabilty rules").
(iii) If "in the middle" means "in the singularity", the statement is void of meaning because the singularity isn't part of spacetime. In the singularity, time and space do not exist.

Statement b: "When I drop a stone in a black hole and the stone ends up in the singularity, the amount of mass-energy is conserved." My objection:
(iv) In general relativity, conservation of mass-energy is only valid locally, in an approximately flat region of spacetime. Near the singularity, spacetime becomes so strongly curved that conservation of mass-energy is no longer valid.

My questions: are both statements indeed false (or meaningless) and are my objections correct?

Comment: No matter how close you get to the singularity, spacetime is still locally flat. This is what it means to be a manifold.

Comment: *central region where the Planck mass density is reached* There is no such place. In a Schwarzschild or Kerr black hole there is vacuum and there is singularity and there is nothing else.

Comment: Physicists often say that time is what clocks measure, but they don’t necessarily think that the absence of clocks means the absence of time.

Comment: The tidal forces at the event horizon are not necessarily as great as you seem to think.  What's your support for (i)?

Comment: @Brick As I understand, the tidal forces near the event horizon of a stellar mass black hole are much greater than near the horizon of a supermassive black hole; enough to destroy a conventional watch. The closer a clock gets to the singularity, forces increase without bound, if I'm correct.

Comment: I wonder why the question has earned a downvote?

Comment: The nature of time inside the event horizon does not depend on whether it is stellar mass or supermassive nor does it depend on the quality of your watch construction. I don't see anything in your argument that makes sense so far...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us who the authors are or given references for the quote. Why? This means we get no context.

> "In the middle of a black hole time progresses normally."

Without context, this is a meaningless statement. We don't know what is meant by "middle" here. Most likely they just mean the interior region, not the singularity (which is not a point at the center). It's also pretty meaningless to talk about whether time "progresses normally" or not. If time were to progress abnormally, it would have to be abnormal compared to something else.

> "When I drop a stone in a black hole and the stone ends up in the singularity, the amount of mass-energy is conserved."

This is true.

> In general relativity, conservation of mass-energy is only valid locally, in an approximately flat region of spacetime.

Local conservation of mass-energy is valid regardless of whether spacetime is flat.

In an asymptotically flat spacetime, the ADM mass is conserved. There is no requirement that it be flat in general, just asymptotically flat.

> Near the singularity, spacetime becomes so strongly curved that conservation of mass-energy is no longer valid.

When we say that mass-energy is conserved in an asymptotically flat spacetime, we mean the total mass on any Cauchy surface. Cauchy surfaces, by definition, do not intersect the singularity. The singularity lies in the future relative to any Cauchy surface.